# Passing different value than provided in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

Okey guys, I really need your help... I'm new here in rails world and seems to be stuck on a pretty basic stuff.

I have a form (using `simple_form_for`) like this:

```
= simple_form_for :search, url: places_path do |p|
  = p.input :group_name, :as => :autocomplete, :source_array => @groups.map { |g| g.name }
  = p.input :start_date, placeholder: Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), :input_html => { :id => 'start_date_picker' }
  = p.input :end_date, placeholder: Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), :input_html => { :id => 'end_date_picker' }
  = p.input :computer_lab, as: :boolean, boolean_style: :inline
  = p.button :submit
```

When user types something in the first input `group_name` he get suggestions and it's fine but what I need to is to have ability to pass diferent value (different instance variable from model) than this inside input.

Here is my `Group` model:

```
class Group
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :id, :name, :type, :type_name
end
```

And when user hits `Submit` I need to pass `:id` rather than `:name`. **HOW!?** I'm stuck here... My temporary solution is passing `:name` and under `places_path` getting all groupd once again and looking for group with provided name to get it's id... It feels like I'm trying to reinvent wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your group_controller.rb. But it seems like your parameters aren't set to id. Try something like this in your controller:

```
def create
  @group = Group.new(params[:id])
  # followed by your save arguments
end
```

Hope  this helps

Comment: I don't have group_controller because I don't store them in database. My service is only passing data from other service.